# Mysql - reuse calculated values like st_distance_sphere value

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, query-performance

My mysql (v8.0.19) test table has 1000 location entries. 250 of them I get as a result if I query "give me all userIds which are within a 500 meter radius".

My first query (0.033 sec) returns only userId:

```
SELECT db_user_id 
FROM db.location 
where st_distance_sphere(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(51.1065133 11.1245543)', 4326), geo) <= 500;
```

My second query (0.045 sec) returns userId and distance:

```
SELECT db_user_id,st_distance_sphere(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(51.1065133 11.1245543)', 4326), geo) 
FROM db.location 
where st_distance_sphere(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(51.1065133 11.1245543)', 4326), geo) <= 500;
```

My guess (why the second query is slower):
The st_distance_sphere is calculated in the where statement (for the 1000 location entries) and again for the result of around 250 entries.

My Question: 
Is there a way to reuse the already calculated st_distance_sphere as query result? Is there a query that is as fast as the first one but returns userId and distance?

Answer (score 1):

Both queries must run the `WHERE` 1000 times.

You shrink the second query down to only 1000 evaluations by making it more complex:

```
SELECT  user_id, dist
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  db_user_id,
                  st_distance_sphere(ST_GeomFromText(
                        'POINT(51.1065133 11.1245543)', 4326), geo
                           ) AS dist
              FROM  db.location 
        ) AS x
    WHERE  dist <= 500;
```

If your list will grow significantly, see my discussion of further optimizations:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql .